# Word 2007, VSTO get default save location

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

From within my VSTO Word code, I need to get the path to where the document was created from (new Document). In this case its a SharePoint document library containing some folders. So the value I'm looking for is something like `http://myserver/mysite/documents/folder/`. Of course the location is different from time to time.

Word has the value in its save file dialog, but is there an easy/any way to get it from code ? C# is preferred.

Answer (score 2):

```
string defaultPath = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Options.DefaultFilePath[Word.WdDefaultFilePath.wdDocumentsPath];
```

[MSDN Options Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.options_members.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string path = Globals.ThisDocument.Application.ActiveDocument.Path;
```

MSDN Reference [Document Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb241569.aspx)

This is worth a try too:

```
Word.Template template = (Word.Template)this.Application.ActiveDocument.get_AttachedTemplate();
string path = template.Path;
```

MSDN Reference [Template Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb225752.aspx)

Comment: Sadly the solution you sugested return an empty string, but thanks for the quick answer

Regards Carsten

Comment: If the document has not been saved, you're correct - no path will exist. I'll look into finding out where the template path can be found.

Comment: Thanks Mike

But this returns the path c:\Documents and Setting\Application Data\Microsoft\Templates

I also have been able to get the URL to the document library by getting the path of the Document Information Panel. but cannot get the location from where the "new document" button was executed.

Thanks for trying, please let me know if you have other ideers.

/regards

Comment: Any news here about this issue? I face the same. Also looking for the real Local folder where the file is stored, rather than the remote synced one.